# How do i use forever to run a Nuxt.js app?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, forever

How do i use forever to run a Nuxt.js app? I've tried every which way and it just doesn't work.

I think i'm not just clear what the equivalent of the app.js file is, so that I can do a simple

```
forever start <entry-point>.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the command that runs nuxt. Example for "npm start":

```
forever start -c "npm start" /path/to/app/dir/
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me, I even tried giving my `yarn` location, but its stopped in forever.